# Discrete Binomial Distribution verify answer

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

> A machine requires all five of its micro controllers to
> operate correctly in order to pass acceptability tests. The
> probability of the installed micro controller type operating correctly
> is 0.99.
>
> (a) What is the probability that the machine passes
> acceptability tests?

My answer is as follows

P (Passes acceptability test micro controllers)

As there are 5 micro controllers
P (5)

The formula we were taught to use

5C5 *  $.99^5$  * (1-.99)$(5-5)$

= 1* .95

= .95

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site, then edit your question.  If you want to write $a^{b - c}$, type `$a^{b - c}$`.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula has $(5-5)$ in it, which means that unless I'm misinterpreting it, you have: $$^5C_5(0.99)^5(1-0.99)(5-5)=^5C_5(0.99)^5(1-0.99)(0)=0,$$
which is already wrong. Since all five of your controllers need to work, all you need to do is $(0.99)^5\approx0.95$ (reading it more carefully, I realize that you might be trying to say $(1-0.99)^{(5-5)}$, which is correct). In general, if $X\sim B(n,p)$, we have $$P(X=x)=~^nC_xp^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}.$$